# Guidance with multiple PHP queries

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm trying to display the results from 3 separate queries in 3 adjacent `<div>` containers. The three queries are as follows:

```
$query="SELECT * FROM students WHERE WeekOne='employer'";
$query="SELECT * FROM students WHERE WeekTwo='employer'";
$query="SELECT * FROM students WHERE WeekThree='employer'";
```

Desired output:

> WEEK ONE ----- WEEK TWO ----- WEEK THREE
>
> Result 1 ---------- Result 1 ----------- Result 1
>
> Result 2 ---------- Result 2 ----------- Result 2
>   (etc...)

Can anybody help me with this? I've seen the multi_query on PHP manual but have no idea how to implement this. Many thanks.

@Emmanuel G

```
<?

$user = "xx";
$user_password = "xx";
$db_name = "xx";
$db = new mysqli ("xx", $user, $user_password, $db_name);

$queries = array(
    "SELECT * FROM students WHERE WeekOne='$Name'",
    "SELECT * FROM students WHERE WeekTwo='$Name'",
    "SELECT * FROM students WHERE WeekThree='$Name'"
);

// iterate through the queries and their results
foreach($queries as $query){
    $result = $mysqli->query($query);
    echo '<div>'; // open that div up
    while($row    = $result->fetch_assoc()){       // gives u an array hoorah!
        echo '<pre>'.print_r($row, true).'</pre>'; // just to look at it
        echo "<p>{$row['FirstName']}</p>";              // just an example
    }
    echo '</div>'; // close it up
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is change the query to this:

```
$query="SELECT * FROM students WHERE WeekOne='employer' OR WeekTwo='employer' OR WeekThree='employer'";
```

And then format the output accordingly.

Comment: How would I format the output though if I did it like that? I want to display all the data for each query.

Comment: You need to use `while` loops to output query data - this is a Q&A site not a general "teach me to program" site :) have a go at a few things and ask specific questions if you get stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, change your query to bring your all result in one query request, then you manipulate from the data result, hitting multiple time for simple answer to the server is not a best practice, because your query is very simple.

but for your question

```
multi_query($query)  //you can use this
```

have a look here http://suite101.com/article/how-tor-run-multiple-mysql-queries-with-php-a105672

Comment: I don't know how to go about manipulating the data after the query is sent... Could you please provide more info?

Answer (score 0):

To display it just iterate over each individual result and place that into a div. To make them adjacent you would add some css to your div's to float them since divs are inherently block elements and don't line up horizontally without some help.

Assuming you already have your database connection set up and should be using mysqli or the such you could generate your markup like so:

```
// u should try to make this one query but that's irrelevant to the question 
// so I'll leave that to you to do later
$queries = array(
    "SELECT * FROM students WHERE WeekOne='employer'",
    "SELECT * FROM students WHERE WeekTwo='employer'",
    "SELECT * FROM students WHERE WeekThree='employer'"
);

// iterate through the queries and their results
foreach($queries as $query){
    if($result = $mysqli->query($query)){// only do stuff if you get a result
        echo '<div>';                                  // open that div up
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){          // gives u an array hoorah!
            echo '<pre>'.print_r($row, true).'</pre>'; // just to look at it
            echo "<p>{$row['data']}</p>";              // just an example
        }
        echo '</div>';                                 // close it up

        // mysqli free the result to prep for the next one
        $result->free();
    } else {
        echo "Query failed to return results:\n$query\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that but it's not working for me. Can you take a look at the whole code and let me know where I'm going wrong? I've added it to my original post.

Comment: Hey @PhilHowell. I am sorry that it isn't working for you. I updated my answer to check if a query isn't returning a result and also added free() to keep with the correct use of mysqli. My question to you is whether you are actually getting results of any sort or any errors in your connection to the database.

Answer (score -1):

i am guessing you are passing employer as URL parameter , so in either way you can also pass which `week` you want to compare with, let's say

```
$week = $_GET['weekOne'];
$employer = $_GET['employer'];

$query="SELECT * FROM students WHERE $week= $employer";
```

make sure you `escape` your data before executing query,to avoid sql injections

i hope it will help you. Thanks

Comment: Only do this if you want to loose all your data. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection